# Base64 decode issue in URL query parameter data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tsx

From another environment we are getting the dynamic base64 encoded data on URL query parameter. So here we need to decode the query from URL and fetch the data to the field.

URL with base64encode: https://login.amaf.ae/SitePages/Contact-Us.aspx?P25hbWU9SGFzc2FuIElicmFoaW0gQWhtYWQgSHVrYWwmbW9iaWxlPTA1MDY5OTM4NjkmZW1haWw9c2FtYXIucXV0b2JAZ21haWwuY29tJmxhbmd1YWdlPWVu

So here I tried with this code to decode.

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const decodedQuery = atob(urlParams.tostring());
const decodedParams = new URLSearchParams(decodedQuery);

  console.log("Decoded Params:", decodedQuery + "URL: " + urlParams);
  const paramsname = decodedParams.get('name');
  const paramsmail = decodedParams.get('email');
  const paramsmobile = decodedParams.get('mobile');

$("#your-name-enq").val(paramsname);
$("#your-email-enq").val(paramsmail);
$("#your-mobile-enq").val(paramsmobile);
```

But this gave an empty result on name, mail, mobile. So please modify the expected code on the above.
Thanks in Advance.